# Getting mongodb authentication failed error

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, mlab

I'm using playframework -v 1.2.4, and using the morphia plugin. When I run play test, and connect with mongolab db, an exception is thrown with the following error:

```
Oops: RuntimeException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception RuntimeException:
MongoDB authentication failed: mydb
```

My application.conf as follows..,

```
application.mode=dev
%prod.application.mode=prod
morphia.db.host=ds033187.mongolab.com
morphia.db.port=33187
morphia.db.username=demo
morphia.db.password=demo
morphia.db.name=mydb
```

But the above credentials are able to connect with mongodb

```
D:\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.1\bin>mongo ds033187.mongolab.com:33187/mydb -u demo -p demo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.1
connecting to: ds033187.mongolab.com:33187/mydb
>
```

But i get connection with mongodb shell. Why i'am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using the [PlayMorphia](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia) module, and taking a [quick look at the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia-1.2.6a/start#config), it uses "morphia.db.seeds" instead of "morphia.db.host".

It could be that, since "seeds" is not specified, the morphia module is connecting to the localhost.

Comment: It can run with localhost. But problem is to run with "Mongolab". Does play framework support mongolab

Comment: Play is ontop of Morphia, which is ontop of the official Java Mongo Driver. I do not see why mongolab would not be supported. The Mongo protocol is rather simple, and after the socket connection is outside of your computer, monogolab should not be able to tell the difference between the java client, or the terminal client.

Answer (score 0):

had the exact same problem. 
i suppose you added the user via

```
use admin
db.addUser( "user", "pw" )
```

however, play morphia does seem to authenticate against the very db you're using, not against the admin db. the following solved my problem:

```
/path/to/mongo
use admin
db.auth( "user", "pw" )
use myDatabase
db.addUser( "user", "pw" )
```

now it should work :)